# Display connected to Quadro on 435 Driver not showing any image

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 19.10

I just did a fresh install of xubuntu 19.10 with `uname -a` returning

`Linux DESKTOP 5.3.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 09:22:33 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

During installation I chose to connect to the internet and let the installer get all the updates and graphics drivers and the like.

I now have the issue that my Quadro card (which I honestly just got because from what I heard NVIDIA drivers are a lot less fiddly than AMD ones...) is not displaying anything.

It is recognized by the addtional drivers utility:
[See this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX6O8.png)
and the latest and greatest recommended drivers are installed.

It is also properly detected by `lspci -k` as seen
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XXNF.png) (it is in fact a K600).

The content in `/var/log/gpu-manager.log` is:

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.3.0-23-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia module: nvidia-modeset.ko
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.3.0-23-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? yes
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? no
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? yes
Is amdgpu loaded? yes
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 1002:130f
BusID "PCI:0@0:1:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver.
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:ffa
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? no
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 2
Has amd? yes
Has intel? no
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 2
Has the system changed? No
Unsupported discrete card vendor: 10de
Nothing to do
```

Which I find to be quite unconclusive.

Why in the world would Nvidia be an unsupported vendor (turns out 10de is the PCI Vendor ID for Nvidia)?

Also why in the world should the card not be bound to any driver if the OS installer did just install the recommended and tested driver for the card?

And most importantly: How do I get that card working (under Windows 10 it is working just fine so it is not a faulty card)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I "solved" the problem. Ubuntu seems to be picky about the graphics device being used as I have an option in the BIOS that sets either the integrated graphics or the PCI/PCIe attached graphics as the primary graphics device (ie. the one that is also used by the BIOS and GRUB). Changing that setting to the PCIe graphics does make the Quadro display an image just fine and it also seems like the graphics are generated on the card (instead of generated by the CPU and only output by the card) as the GPU Utilization in the NVIDIA X Server Settings app (which now also has content and is no longer entirely blank as before) is a meaningful value that correlates to actions on the screen (ie. idleing shows low number, moving around a window very very quickly results in an a bit higher number)...

By the way now the integrated graphics does not produce any images on attached monitors. But thats fine since I am in a single monitor setup anyway and since the NVIDIA card was only gathered because the driver installation for them is a walk in the park (unlike the basically unguided mess we have with the AMD drivers where there are like 5 different places to get them 100 different "tutorials" on how to install them, all being horribly outdated and not leading to any usable result in my case).